# display user input text on the same window of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, whatsapp

can anyone plz help me got strucked at this point i want to display user       enterd text on the same windowfor andriod app. i want to display the value of text box on my screen as like chatapps

here is my code of main .xml

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setTitle("aakash");

      SetContentView(R.id.lst);

      Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);
      b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(View.this,View.class));    
        }
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);


    }
     public void setText(){
            Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            final EditText myInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    myText.setText(myInput.getText()); 
                }
            });    
        }

    }
this way its work
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to place a listView in xml-layout. then made these changes in .java file:

```
 final ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
```

// On each button Pressed add message to messageList

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
        messages.add (YourWrittenText);    
    }
});
```

// populate the listView with messages Array

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```